# What is the Latin and Greek phrase or word for golden chariot?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, greek-translation

I am currently writing about the ancient Greek and Roman gods, and I am looking to find the correct phrase for a chariot drawn by four horses made of gold. The closest I have come using google is khrūsoûs tethrippon (χρυσοῦς τέθριππον) /quadriga aureolus. Also, any help in a possessive adjective, such as Helios' golden chariot would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the Greek for Apollo's golden chariot would be ἅρμα χρύσεον Ἀπόλλωνος. I don't think Apollo's chariot would be τέθριππον, which means "four-horse," since it's actually pulled by swans.

I get the impression from WP that Helios was not really a big deal in classical Greek culture until the Romans exerted an influence back on the Greeks. But if you really want Helios with the iconography of the four horses, then I think it would be τέθριππον χρύσεον Ἠελίοιο. The word for the god is just the word for the sun, so this is "the four-horsed, golden chariot of the Sun."

Comment: For my purposes, I am treating Helios and Apollo as two separate deities, so both terms you shared were equally helpful. Apollo's chariot can be pulled by swans while Helios' can be pulled by horses.

Answer (score 2):

aureus currus = golden chariot    (in Latin)

Answer (score 2):

From [Pausanias's *Description of Greece* II.3.2](https://loebclassics.com/view/pausanias-description_greece/1918/pb_LCL093.259.xml):

> Ἐκ δὲ τῆς ἀγορᾶς ἐξιόντων τὴν ἐπὶ Λεχαίου προπύλαιά ἐστι καὶ ἐπ᾿ αὐτῶν **ἅρματα ἐπίχρυσα**, τὸ μὲν Φαέθοντα Ἡλίου παῖδα, τὸ δὲ Ἥλιον αὐτὸν φέρον.
>
> *For anyone leaving the forum on the road to Lechaeum, there is a gateway, and on top of it are **gilded chariots**, one carrying Phaethon son of Helios, the other carrying Helios himself.*

(Translation mine.)

Which seems like good ancient evidence that Helios had a ἅρμα, not a τέθριππος. The real one, presumably, would be χρυσόν (gold) rather than ἐπίχρυσον (gilded).